# Prove that $f$ is injective if and only if $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x \; \; \forall x \in A$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that a function $f$ is injective if and only if $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x \; \; \forall x \in A.$ I don't know how to solve it. Can anyone please help me prove it.

Comment: You must restate the problem or question in the body, not depend on the title. As it is, I have no idea what the question is, ’cause your notation is ambiguous, nonstandard, or misleading.

Comment: Use the definitions: What is $f(x)$ when $x$ is a subset instead of element of the domain? What is the definition of $f^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2):

First Recall the definition of an Injective function (I prefer the term one-one function):

> A function $f:A \rightarrow \textbf{R} $ is said to be one-one if $ \forall x,y \in A, \; f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y $

Now, assume that $f^{-1}(f(x)) =x \; \; \; \forall x \in A $.  Now consider
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x)&=&f(y) \\
\Rightarrow f^{-1}(f(x)) &=& f^{-1}(f(y)) \\
\Rightarrow x&=&y
\end{eqnarray*}

Can you prove the other way now?

Comment: Please do no not answer questions that do not meet the [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).